# Acces to a class property gives me the error : TypeError: Cannot read/set property 'x' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I just started experimenting with JavaScript / TypeScript and I'm building a simple React App in TypeScript.
In one of my component I want to be able to change the component via a "state" (the components will succeed one another).

I'm doing this via a class property `whichComponentsToShow` with a type of an enum `ComponentsToShow`.
In the render I just do a simple condition check on my property and change the components to render.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import Init from './Init';
    import SetupTask from './SetupTask';
    import ExecutingTask from './ExecutingTask';
    import Finish from './Finish';


    enum ComponentsToShow {
        Init = 0,
        Setup = 1,
        Executing = 2,
        Finish = 3,
    }

    class Body extends Component {

        whichComponentsToShow: ComponentsToShow;

        constructor(props: any){
            super(props);

            this.whichComponentsToShow = ComponentsToShow.Init;
        }

        advanceComponentsToShow(){
            console.log(this.whichComponentsToShow);
            this.whichComponentsToShow = ComponentsToShow.Setup;  
        }

        render(){
            return(
                <div>
                    { this.whichComponentsToShow === ComponentsToShow.Init  &&
                        <Init onValidation={this.advanceComponentsToShow}/>
                    }
                    { this.whichComponentsToShow === ComponentsToShow.Setup  &&
                        <SetupTask/>
                    }
                    { this.whichComponentsToShow === ComponentsToShow.Executing  &&
                        <ExecutingTask/>
                    }
                    { this.whichComponentsToShow === ComponentsToShow.Finish  &&
                        <Finish/>
                    }
                </div>
            );
        }

    }



    export default Body;
```

I'm doing a callback on the `Init` component which let me call the function `advanceComponentsToShow()`.

It's in this function that I receive the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'whichComponentsToShow' of undefined". I can't really determine why this property would be undefined here.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind `advanceComponentsToShow` function to make sure it have access to component attributes

There are several ways

### Bind in constructor

```
constructor(props: any){
  super(props);

  this.whichComponentsToShow = ComponentsToShow.Init;
  this.advanceComponentsToShow = this.advanceComponentsToShow.bind(this)
}
```

### use arrow function instead

```
advanceComponentsToShow = () => {
  console.log(this.whichComponentsToShow);
  this.whichComponentsToShow = ComponentsToShow.Setup;  
}
```

### Bind in render

```
<Init onValidation={this.advanceComponentsToShow.bind(this)}/>
```

### Arrow Function in Render

```
<Init onValidation={() => this.advanceComponentsToShow()}/>
```

Comment: I didn’t know that we needed to bind the function, I’ll test that tonight. Thanks !

Comment: PS: Do you know why we need to bind the function ? I come from other languages so it’s a little bit weird to me.

Comment: this is javascript, my english is't so good, let these article [Binding functions in React](https://codeburst.io/binding-functions-in-react-b168d2d006cb) [this-is-why-we-need-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb/) explain to you